# How can I post data to mailchimp list through my page

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm having a newsletter popup in my web page page which has three fields: e-mail, Birth month and birth date. So if the user fills in these data and clicks on submit I want these data to be written in the mailchimp list.
Is there any way I can do that ?

Thank you

Comment: You should consider to add some code, how you implemented the API. Without any informations, no one can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function syncMailchimp($data) { 
    $apiKey = 'your api key';
    $listId = 'your list id';

    $memberId = md5(strtolower($data['email']));
    $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
    $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listId . '/members/' . $memberId;

    $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $data['email'],
        'status'        => $data['status'], // "subscribed","unsubscribed","cleaned","pending"
        'merge_fields'  => [
            'FNAME'     => $data['firstname'],  // You can add your fields here
            'LNAME'     => $data['lastname'],
            'DOB'       => 'mm/dd',  // Add your date of birth here in mm/dd format
        ]
    ]);

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);                                                                                                                 

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $httpCode;
}
```

Comment: What is the $data parameter in the function syuncMail($data)?

Comment: You can use it without function. In that case just use $_POST instead of $data

Comment: My form is like echo $this->getFormAction().   So I'll put your snippet inside this function and inside as a parameter I'll put it like:  $this->getFormActionUrl ($_POST)   ??

Comment: I'm getting a weird error:   when I'm trying to sign up as a new customer, there is a checkbox underneath the "Register now" button, that says "Subscribe to our newsletter".  If I have the checkbox selected and click on register I get this error: "Resource Not Found for Api Call: lists//members/c07a81da48152b494b8ee673c7e7acc3 - The requested resource could not be found."  I want to be able to register to the mailing chimp list too when signing up.  So any idea what this error is?  Thank you

Comment: what must be passed via the "status"-field? if i pass subscribed..users are already subscribed...which is not with the mailchimp-standard..if i pass "pending" nothing happens i dont see it in the data-center...if i pass nothing we get an error..we need something like "new" to indicate this user still must click on his activation-link. and how can we automatize to send out the activation-email?

Comment: oh it works just by passing "pending", automated email will be sent out..everthing is fine!

Comment: You can get the status from here. https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/